# screenshots from snipping tool should be saved in what format so that google drive links can be fetched as image in stackexchange sites

Tags: support, site-recommendation, hyperlinks, images, uploader

I keep facing a lot of problems on my systems. So I keep posting on stack exchange sites. I take a lot of screenshots from snipping tool
for example this one
https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1Nk70pJTyo0i95UO8a5JOpbds4i2QFA9Q
I posted on this link [what could be cause of my slow running laptop on windows 10](https://superuser.com/questions/1507247/what-could-be-cause-of-my-slow-running-laptop-on-windows-10/1508614?noredirect=1#comment2280686_1508614)
also see these links in comments a lot of google drive screenshot links I 
gave

- [internet connectivity failure in virtual machines on workstation](https://serverfault.com/questions/994622/internet-connectivity-failure-in-virtual-machines-on-workstation)
- [nslookup failures *** UnKnown can't find www.vmware.com: Query refused](https://serverfault.com/questions/994722/nslookup-failures-unknown-cant-find-www-vmware-com-query-refused)

I many a times am in a situation where I have taken a screenshot and uploaded it in my google drive and I want to post it on stack exchange group of sites. But when I press image button in question typing box and try to fetch image from google drive I get an error file format not supported. So I am wondering in which file format should I save my screenshots taken by snip and sketch tool on Windows 10 so that when I share them from Google drive then they can be easily fetched.

Comment: Note that you can upload an image into a post straight from your computer, without first uploading it to Google Drive.

Comment: @V2Blast in the comments on those links I posted images that probably were used somewhere else also in questions.I was new to server fault and needed to lost links to image as with less than 10 reputation I can not post image in question.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you take screenshots with the snipping tool (as I do), just open the post editor and paste it (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd>) in the body of the post.

The reason that Google Drive link doesn't work is that it's not an image link rather a link to a Google Drive *preview page* containing the image/file.