# why cant a publicly accessible image not be posted when I press fetch image

Tags: support, images, uploader

I wanted to post an image link in this thread
[how to use recovery usb created by hp recovery tool to re install windows 10](https://superuser.com/questions/1512183/how-to-use-recovery-usb-created-by-hp-recovery-tool-to-re-install-windows-10/1512184?noredirect=1#comment2287553_1512184)

since my image of BIOS boot options of my laptop was taken from a camera its size was 4 Mb or so I had already posted the image here

https://www.tenforums.com/attachments/general-support/260463d1577150376-how-boot-into-recovery-mode-using-usb-created-hp-usb-recovery-so-img_20191224_034636.jpg

so I tried giving a link to image but I got error
[image: image from tenforums upload error]

previously I had asked uploading image from google drive screenshots from snipping tool should be saved in what format so that google drive links can be fetched as image in stackexchange sites
[screenshots from snipping tool should be saved in what format so that google drive links can be fetched as image in stackexchange sites](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/340021/screenshots-from-snipping-tool-should-be-saved-in-what-format-so-that-google-dri)

and I came to know that the google drive image links were  not link to images.
Now this time I try to fetch an image posted on other forum then what is the problem. In my humble opinion I think I gave URL which ended with a .jpg extension so I am assuming this is a link to valid image.
If not then what better can I do because I tried to compress this image after this error and then upload again I got another error
[image: an error occured uploading image]

**edit**
after the answer below I double checked I logged out from all the browser window in chrome 
I can read it without logging in https://www.tenforums.com/general-support/147078-how-boot-into-recovery-mode-using-usb-created-hp-usb-recovery-so.html
so I don't need to login to read the thread and I can easily see the image I wanted to post 
https://www.tenforums.com/attachments/general-support/260463d1577150376-how-boot-into-recovery-mode-using-usb-created-hp-usb-recovery-so-img_20191224_034636.jpg

**I can right click and view html source and from there I copy paste the image link for the image which I want to be fetched and when I am doing so I am not logged in.**

Why can't the image which I can see clearly in browser I not fetch here in the image feed while posting question what did I miss here?

**update 1**
I forgot to mention above I am using a new browser it is still under testing and is based on Chromium
https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/edge/forum/all/new-version-of-edge-on-its-way/26120d7b-d462-4bdb-9301-deda8985f1e6

and here I was not even able to post link to images citing I needed reputation of 10 and above and if you see the screenshot below I clearly had 125 points and I was logged in when I posted the question
[image: need more than 10 reputation to post images]

Well this is a problem in way stackexchange functions.On many websites fetching images is problem I am just reporting a broken functionality.

*There are no dumb questions, just the people who do not ask them.*

I asked a simple question and I disagree with the answer given and I see 9 downvotes at the time of writing this here.
Why is this kind of friction for disagreement 
https://hackernoon.com/the-decline-of-stack-overflow-7cb69faa575d

Answer (score 11):

## That TenForums site is password protected and/or is restricting image linking so only TenForum pages can show images.

### This has nothing to do with JPEG sizing or formatting. If the URL to the image is not accessible outside of TenForums it can’t be added here.

You can’t add that picture to Stack Exchange — or honestly anywhere — since the TenForums site is password protected and has logic in place to prevent external image linking. When I try to click on the image I see this; screenshot attached below

> “You are not logged in or you do not have permission to access this page. This could be due to one of several reasons:”

But if I visit the forum post directly I can see the image:

> https://www.tenforums.com/general-support/147078-how-boot-into-recovery-mode-using-usb-created-hp-usb-recovery-so.html

I can see the thread as well, so they must have image linking disabled for non-TenForum referrers. Meaning that image can load if is requested by a page loaded from TenForums. But non-TenForum URLs, that image will not load. It’s easy to setup a website to do something like this to prevent image linking and save on bandwidth; only serve images if the referrer is a page on that TenForum website itself.

To add an image via URL the image has to be publicly accessible. If you wish to use the same image, just download it to your computer and manually re-upload it here.

[image]

Comment: sorry about that I was not aware of such a thing to login here is the thread https://www.tenforums.com/general-support/147078-how-boot-into-recovery-mode-using-usb-created-hp-usb-recovery-so.html and I think this is the image I wanted to post https://www.tenforums.com/attachments/general-support/260463d1577150376-how-boot-into-recovery-mode-using-usb-created-hp-usb-recovery-so-img_20191224_034636.jpg may be I could not get a correct link while inserting the link

Comment: I just want to know one thing is that question on tenforum which I gave link not publicly accessible without logging in. If that question is accessible without logging in then that image should also be accessible publicly. I just double checked I logged out from all forums in chrome and then clicked that link https://www.tenforums.com/attachments/general-support/260463d1577150376-how-boot-into-recovery-mode-using-usb-created-hp-usb-recovery-so-img_20191224_034636.jpg no login asked.

Comment: "Then download it to your machine and just upload it." Or just post the image on imgur or some similar specialized image hosting service before linking to it here.

Comment: There is something weird on that site. If you visit the thread it is public and the image loads. If you only GET the image you need to login. Download and re-upload is the way to go.